# Sorting timestamps queried with SQL using Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I'm dealing with a situation where a `Parent` class has many `Children`. In my view I am displaying each parents last child to sign in to the app. To do this I created a scope `last_child_sign_in` on my Parent model that does a complex sql query. I put that scope in my controller so that it has `@search = Parent.last_child_sign_in.search(params[:q])`. I then run another query on top of that result to get an `Order` count from an associated orders table.

In my view I have a `sort_link(@search, :last_child_sign_in, 'Last login')`, that sends `Parameters: {"q"=>{"s"=>"last_child_sign_in desc"}}` to the controller but it does not affect the sorting of the @search object at all. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After much fiddling with this issue I came to the conclusion that **Ransack just can't handle sorting in this situation**. I ended up creating logic to manually sort the column using SQL like this in the controller:

```
if( sorting_by_last_child_sign_in? )
  if( params[:q][:s].ends_with? 'asc' )
    direction = "DESC NULLS LAST"
  else
    direction = "ASC NULLS LAST"
  end
  parents_scope = 
    parents_scope.order( "MAX(child_users.current_sign_in_at 
    AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US/PACIFIC') #{direction}" )
end
```

I love me some Ransack, but sometimes you just have to do things the old fashioned way.